# Conectar contador de tempo com o datetime do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Galera estou com o esse script porém não consigo conectar com o banco de dados de jeito nenhum, algúem me ajuda por favor??

está funcionando perfeitamente dessa forma, mais preciso puxar a data do banco de dados.

Está retornando esse erros:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\listar\listar_usuario.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\listar\listar_usuario.php on line 12

Oque está no banco de dados --> 2019-02-25 12:47:27
Como ele deveria apresentar --> 1 dia, 2 horas, 8 minutos e 4 segs atrás

```
    <?php
include_once "conexao.php";

//consultar no banco de dados
$result_usuario = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_acesso, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s') as data_acesso FROM adms_ultimos_acessos ORDER BY id DESC;";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario) ;
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario ); // <--- esta linha
$adms_ultimos_acessos = preg_replace("(\:|\s)", "-", $registro['data_acesso']);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = str_replace(":", "-", $registro['data_acesso']);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = str_replace(" ", "-", $adms_ultimos_acessos);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $registro['data_acesso']);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = $adms_ultimos_acessos->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');

//Verificar se encontrou resultado na tabela "usuarios"
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_usuario) > 0){
    ?>

<?php                                   
$adms_ultimos_acessos = $registro ['data_acesso']; // <-- aqui está o registro
$databd2 = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$data1   = explode('-', $adms_ultimos_acessos); 
$data2   = explode('-', $databd2);  
$ano     = $data2[0] - $data1[0]; 
$mes     = $data2[1] - $data1[1]; 
$dia     = $data2[2] - $data1[2];  
$hora    = $data2[3] - $data1[3]; 
$min     = $data2[4] - $data1[4]; 
$seg     = $data2[5] - $data1[5];                                   
// configuração data  
if ($mes < 0) {$ano--;  $mes = 12 + $mes; }  
if ($dia < 0) { $mes--;     $dia = 30 + $dia; }  
if ($ano > 0) { $str_ano = $ano . ' ano'; } 
if ($ano > 1) { $str_ano .= 's '; }  
if ($mes > 0) { @$str_mes .= $mes . ' mes'; }  
if ($mes > 1) {     
if ($ano > 0) { $str_ano .= ', ';   }   $str_mes .= 'es'; } 
if ($dia > 0) { $str_dia = $dia . ' dia'; }  
if ($dia > 1) {     
if ($mes > 0) { $str_mes .= ', ';   }   $str_dia .= 's'; }                                      
// configuração hora  
if ($min < 0) {$hora--; $min = 60 + $min; }  
if ($seg < 0) { $min--; $seg = 60 + $seg; }  
if ($hora > 0) { $str_hora = $hora . ' hora'; }  
if ($hora > 1) { @$str_hora .= 's'; }  
if ($min > 0) { @$str_min .= $min . ' minuto'; }  
if ($min > 1) {     
if ($hora > 0) { @$str_hora .= ', ';    }   @$str_min .= 's'; }  
if ($seg > 0) { $str_seg = $seg . ' seg'; }  
if ($seg > 1) {     
if ($min > 0) { $str_min .= ' e ';  }   $str_seg .= 's'; }                                      

?>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data acesso</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $row_usuario['data_acesso']; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo @$str_ano, @$str_mes, @$str_dia,', ', @$str_hora, @$str_min, @$str_seg,  ' atrás'; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
}else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Nenhum usuário encontrado!</div>";
}
```

Comment: Esse é o código completo ? porque não tem nada da conexão com o banco de dados.

Comment: Sim editei, a conexão eu fiz porém não consigo puxar os dados de lá entende? não estou conseguindo fazer a parte do SELECT* e inserir na $databd1

Comment: Pelo que entendi eu preciso pegar o valor da consulta e inserir no $databd1 não é?

Comment: Sim, seu select vai retornar apenas esse valor pra ser trabalhado na data?

Comment: Que data você precisa puxar do banco? Data de um registro?

Comment: Mas qual o nome do campo da data? Qual o nome da tabela?

Comment: sso exatamente ele vai funcionar de forma semelhante ao tempo em que o comentário foi adicionado, só que não consigo criar essa parte do SELECT na data do registro, se tiver como me dar um exemplo usando esse meu código ou tiver alguma outra solução que funcione de forma semelhante, me passa o link por favor, muito obrigado desde já

Comment: Você precisa ser mais claro Wesley. Não está dando para entender o que você quer.

Comment: tabela:pesquisar  campo:databd1

Comment: $registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); ao inves de $query seria $resultado_usuario, isso é um dos primeiros erros

Comment: Com a Ajuda do Andrei eu modifiquei algumas coisas vou postar uma nova edição pera ai

Comment: Olá lá como ficou e os erros do retorno.

Comment: Qual o formato da data salva no banco?

Comment: Ele está salvo assim: 2019-02-25 12:47:27 datetime

Comment: acho que o erro está na estrutura que ele está recebendo a data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é o formato da data que está vindo do banco, você está recebendo no formato `aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` e está tratando ela como se estivesse no formato `aaaa-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss`, você precisa converter ela, segue algumas opções para você escolher uma

1. No SQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_acesso, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s") as data_acesso FROM adms_ultimos_acessos ORDER BY id DESC
```

2. No PHP com `preg_replace`:

```
$adms_ultimos_acessos = preg_replace("(\:|\s)", "-", $registro['data_acesso']);
```

3. No PHP com `str_replace`:

```
$adms_ultimos_acessos = str_replace(":", "-", $registro['data_acesso']);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = str_replace(" ", "-", $adms_ultimos_acessos);
```

4. No PHP com `DateTime`:

```
$adms_ultimos_acessos = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $registro['data_acesso']);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = $adms_ultimos_acessos->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
```

Comment: Está dando erro ao inserir SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_acesso, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s") as data_acesso FROM adms_ultimos_acessos ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: ai inserir as linhas:
 $adms_ultimos_acessos = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $registro['data_acesso']);
$adms_ultimos_acessos = $adms_ultimos_acessos->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s'); 

Retorna o erro:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\listar\listar_usuario.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\listar\listar_usuario.php on line 24

Comment: Eu coloquei 4 opções deve usar apenas uma delas

Comment: Acabei de voltar pra ler novamente, ele está formatando mais não está puxando os dados do banco